# Method overloading in child class in java

Tags: java

Is it possible in java **Method overloading** in child class??
if possible then how can differentiate from method overriding ??

Comment: *Self study is always a good thing.* They are just different flavors of polymophism,    read this http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/method-overloading-vs-method-overriding.html

Comment: work on basic , and google it

Answer (score 2):

**Method Overriding (Polymorphism)**

This is where you create a method, with *THE EXACT SAME SIGNATURE* as the method in the parent class. That is:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void sayHello(String name) { System.out.println("Hello " + name); }
}
```

And in the child class:

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public void sayHello(String name) { System.out.println("HELLO" + name);}
}
```

**Method Overloading**

This is where you create a method with the same name, but accepts different parameters.

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public void sayHello(int name) { System.out.println("HELLO" + name);}
    // sayHello is a different method to the JVM, but has the same name.
}
```

**The awesome power of Documentation**

Just as a test to myself, I googled this problem, and the very first link is a comprehensive tutorial from Oracle on this exact topic. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) is the link.